# How to Create a Function to extract data from a JSON file

Tags: python

I am currently extracting trade data from a JSON file to create graphs. I have made a file to load in my JSON data but I want to create a a function that allows me to extract specific data points (Like a getter?), How would I go about this?
So the function is to store the data but Im not sure how to connect it back to my loaded in JSON file.

This is my function so far

```
class TradeInfo():
    
def __init__(self, sym, vol, pChange, gcount):
        self.symbol = sym
        self.volume = vol
        self.pChange = pChange
        self.gcount = gcount

    def getSymbol(self):
        return (self.symbol)

    def getVolume(self):
        return (self.volume)

    def getPriceChange(self):
        return (self.pChange)
    
    def getCount(self):
        return (self.gcount)
```

and below is the output I recive when I load in my Json file in a separate function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0nO7.png)

```
This is the code to load my JSON file
def loadfile(infileName,biDir= True):
    try:
        filename= infileName
        with open(filename) as f:
            fileObj = json.load(f)
            fileObj = json.dumps(fileObj, indent=4)
    except IOError as e:
        print("Error in file processing: " + str(e))
    return fileObj
```

Comment: json.load returns a dict. Just do a myJsonDict.get(“symbolName”, myDefault).

Comment: Very low quality question, that is why I downvoted. Please, read documentation before asking questions.

Comment: lol sorry im panicking

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your `JSON` looks like this:

```
{
    "marketId": "LTC-AUD",
    "bestBid": "67.62",
    "bestAsk": "68.15",
    "lastPrice": "67.75",
    "volume24h": "190.19169781",
    "volumeQte24h": "12885.48752662",
    "price24h": "1.37",
    "pricePct24h": "2.06",
    "low24h": "65.89",
    "high24h": "69.48",
    "timestamp": "2020-10-10T11:14:19.270000Z"
}
```

So your `loadfile` function should look something like this:

```
import json


def load_file(infile_name) -> dict:
    try:
        with open(infile_name) as f:
            return json.load(f)
    except IOError as e:
        print("Error in file processing: " + e)


data = load_file("sample_json.json")

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
print(data['timestamp'])
```

Output:

```
{
  "bestAsk": "68.15",
  "bestBid": "67.62",
  "high24h": "69.48",
  "lastPrice": "67.75",
  "low24h": "65.89",
  "marketId": "LTC-AUD",
  "price24h": "1.37",
  "pricePct24h": "2.06",
  "timestamp": "2020-10-10T11:14:19.270000Z",
  "volume24h": "190.19169781",
  "volumeQte24h": "12885.48752662"
}
2020-10-10T11:14:19.270000Z
```

I've simplified your function and removed a redundant argument `biDir` because you're not using it anywhere.